# is java AtomicReference thread safe when used within parallelStream?

Tags: java, java-8

I used the parallelStream to get the longest string in an array, the code is following, each time it runs, I get different result. `AtomicReference` supposes to be thread safe even when used within parallelStream? But why does this happen?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  AtomicReference<String> longest = new AtomicReference<>();
  LongAccumulator accumulator = new LongAccumulator(Math::max, 0);
  List<String> words = Arrays.asList("him", "he", "thanks", "strings", "congratulations", "platform");
  words.parallelStream().forEach(
          next -> longest.updateAndGet(
                     current -> {
                        String result = next.length() > accumulator.intValue() ? next : current;
                        accumulator.accumulate(next.length());
                        return result;
                     }
                  )
  );
  System.out.println(longest.get());
}
```

for one time, I get “congratulations” printed, and some time I get “platform” printed.

Comment: Is it an option to use `words.parallelStream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));` instead.? I tried it with that and it always returned the same word. However i'm not 100% sure if it gets executed parallel.

Comment: @Clayn: that’s the problem with concurrency—you can never be sure. But I can assert you, that your variant is correct.

Comment: @Holger thanks for the assertion. The first thing that came to my mind was: I'm sure that can be done more elegant using the Stream API

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are invoking [`LongAccumulator.intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html#intValue--) which is documented as:

> Returns the [current value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html#get--) as an int after a narrowing primitive conversion.

and following the linke to the `get()` method we will learn:

> Returns the current value. The returned value is *NOT* an atomic snapshot; invocation in the absence of concurrent updates returns an accurate result, but concurrent updates that occur while the value is being calculated might not be incorporated.

So while the `AtomicReference.updateAndGet` operation is thread safe, your concurrent invocation of `LongAccumulator.intValue()` and `LongAccumulator.accumulate` is not. A `LongAccumulator` is intended for performing concurrent `accumulate` operations, followed by fetching the result *after* all accumulate operations have been finished. Note that even if `get()` was returning a correct snapshot, the fact that the invocation of `intValue()` and the subsequent `accumulate()` are two distinct, hence non-atomic, operations made the operation still prone to data races.

In most cases, if you find yourself trying to manipulate data structures in a `forEach`, you are using the wrong tool for the job, making the code unnecessarily complicated and error prone.
As Clayn [hinted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249526/is-java-atomicreference-thread-safe-when-used-within-parallelstream#comment65835669_39249526), a 
`words.parallelStream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::l‌​ength))` will do the job concisely and correct.

Answer (score 4):

Actually i was writing about the issue which @Holger mentioned already, i was a bit late, but i am writing this anyway as a proof of [@Holger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39250487/1601571). You can use **AtomicReference**'s accumulator;

Here is the code :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AtomicReference < String > longest = new AtomicReference < > ();
    List < String > words = Arrays.asList("him", "he", "thanks", "strings", "congratulations", "platform");

    words.parallelStream().forEach(next - > {
        longest.accumulateAndGet(next, (a, b) - >
            a != null && a.length() > b.length() ? a : b
        );
    });

    System.out.println(longest.get());
}
```